# Probability that you win the prize

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Ten million people enter a certain lottery. For each person, the chance of winning is one in ten million, independently.

Congratulations! You won the lottery. However, there may be other winners. Assume
now that the number of winners other than you is W ⇠ Pois(1), and that if there is
more than one winner, then the prize is awarded to one randomly chosen winner. Given
this information, find the probability that you win the prize.

I cam up with the following:
V-"stands for victory"

$P(V)=$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}P(V|W)P(W)$

Can anybody give me a hint of how to find $P(V|W)$?

Comment: It seems to me that $P(V|W) = 1/W$.  Then you "only" have to sum the resulting series.

Comment: I would have thought your expresion might be clearer as $\sum _{w=0}^{\infty}P(V|W=w)P(W=w)$ with, not quite as @awkward says, $P(V|W=w) = 1/(w+1)$, and with $P(W=w)=e^{-1}/w!$.  The problem gets harder if you say "ten million minus one" and "binomial" rather than "infinity" and "Poisson" though numerically it makes little difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** There may be a better way of going about this.

Let $A$ be the event that you have won, $P(A) = 1/N = 10^{-7}$, where $N$ is the number of people. Let $B$ be the event that **at least one person** won, $P(B) \approx 1-e^{-1}$ (from the Poisson).

Since everyone's chances of getting the prize are the same, $P(V) = P(B)/N$. What you actually wanted, it seems, is "victory" (getting prize) conditional on "having won" which is $$
P(V|A) = {P(V\cap A)\over P(A)} =
$$
[I'll let you finish it.]