# Expected value $\frac{1}{x+1}$ of Poisson distribution

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, poisson-distribution, expected-value

> If the random variable $X$ has a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$, derive an expression for the expected value $\frac{1}{X+1}$

My attempt, 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{X+1}\right]
&=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x+1}P(X=x) \\
& =\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x+1}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}.
\end{align*}

I don't know how to proceed anymore so I went to see the given solution, 
the answer is $\frac{1-e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}$.

Comment: A recent related question with $\lambda=1$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517154/probability-that-you-win-the-prize

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note

$$\frac{1}{x+1}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}=\lambda^{-1}e^{-\lambda}\color{red}{\frac{\lambda^{x+1}}{(x+1)!}}$$

Do you recognize the terms in red?