# Ten million people enter a certain lottery. For each person, the chance of winning is one in ten million, independently

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution, lotteries

I am solving the following question in Blitzstein & Hwang:

"Ten million people enter a certain lottery. For each person, the chance of winning is
one in ten million, independently.

(b) Congratulations! You won the lottery. However, there may be other winners. Assume
now that the number of winners other than you is W ~ Pois(1), and that if there is
more than one winner, then the prize is awarded to one randomly chosen winner. Given
this information, findnd the probability that you win the prize (simplify)."

My solution is to use Poisson approximation to first approximate the PMF and then calculate the desired probability.

Calculate the PMF: Let X be a r.v of the number of people who win the lottery. Let $N=10^7$. Then

$$
X=I_1+I_2+...+I_N \\
\lambda=E[X]=P(I_1)+P(I_2)+...+P(I_N)=N 1/N=1
$$
By the Poisson approximation we have then
$$
P(X=k) \approx e^{-1}1^k/k!
$$

Calculate the probability that you win: Let $A$ be the event that you win.  Then, I know that we can calculate this probability by summing over all possible events $W=k$,

$$
\begin{aligned} 
P(A) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(A|W=k)P(W=k) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k+1} \frac{e^{-1} \lambda }{k!} \\
&= e^{-1} (e^1-1) = 1-e^{-1}
\end{aligned} 
$$

Thus, $1-e^{-1}$ is the correct answer. But let us approach this problem from a slightly different angle. Let us seperate the case where I win with certainty $P(A|W=0)=1$ from the events where I do not win with certainty. And use that $P(W >0) =1- P(W =0)=1- \frac{e^{-1} 1 }{0!}=1-e^{-1}$.

$$
\begin{aligned} 
P(A) &= P(A|W=0)P(W=0) + P(A|W >0)P(W >0)  \\
&= 1 e^{-1} + P(A|W >0)(1-e^{-1}) \\
&= e^{-1} +  \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k+1} (1-e^{-1})  \\
 &=  ???
\end{aligned} 
$$

And now the problem is that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1}$  is a sum that diverges, as far as I can see. My question is then how can this second approach lead to a dead end? This second approach of viewing this problem is, for me, a more intuitive view of analyzing the problem. Yet this intuition is leading me to a dead end. Your guidance and comments are most welcomed.

My question is related to [Probability that you win the prize](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517154/probability-that-you-win-the-prize), but mine question is different.

Comment: There aren’t infinitely many ways for you to win, so your summations should not be infinite sums.

Comment: Agreed for the first approach. But the sum in the second approach is divergent, so it needs to be capped somewhere, right?

Comment: Thanks for your input. On the one hand, @bof is right because we are approximating with the Possion distribution that sums over 0 to infinity. On the other hand, the sum is divergent. So something is not adding up and that is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: On the line just above the ???, what makes you think that $P(A|W\gt0)$ is equal to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k+1}$?

Comment: I am arriving at $P(A|W>0)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1}$ from the following. If there are zero winners (W=0) other than me, then $P(A|W=0)= \frac{1}{0+1}$, that is, I win with probability 1.  If there is one other winner (W=1) then $P(A|W=1)= \frac{1}{1+1}$, and my probability is $1/2$. And so on. So I am thinking of $P(A|W>0)$ as the union $P(A|W=1  \cup W=2...  \cup W=N)$. And this union partitions the sample space, and thus summing over it $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1}$. But this sum yields a  probability quantity above 1. So somewhere my logic is flawed but I am not seeing where.

Comment: Your logic is flawed where you wrote "and thus". Let's consider a simpler game. I draw one card from a bridge deck. Event $H$: I draw a "high" card: ace, king, queen, or jack. Event $K$: I draw a king. Event $Q$: I draw a queen. According to your logic, $$P(H|K\cup Q)=P(H|K)+P(H|Q)=1+1=2.$$

Comment: By the way, there is no need for the Poisson approximation (other than that you were told to use it), as it's easy to see that the exact answer is $1-(1-\frac1N)^N$ where $N=$ ten million.

Comment: @bof, thanks for your input. They are clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is the incorrect intuition that

$$ P(A\mid W>0) \stackrel?=
 P(A\mid W=1) + P(A\mid W=2) + \cdots + P(A\mid W=N). $$

Here is a correct formulation:

\begin{align}
P(A\mid W>0) &= \frac{P(A \cap W>0)}{P(W>0)} \\
&= \frac{P(A\cap W=1) + P(A\cap W=2) + \cdots + P(A\cap W=N)}{P(W>0)} \\
&= \frac{P(A\cap W=1)}{P(W>0)} + \frac{P(A\cap W=2)}{P(W>0)} + \cdots + \frac{P(A\cap W=N)}{P(W>0)} \\
\end{align}

Now since $P(W>0) > P(W=k)$ for any $k,$ clearly

\begin{align}
 \frac{P(A\cap W=1)}{P(W>0)} &< \frac{P(A\cap W=1)}{P(W=1)} = P(A\mid W=1),\\
 \frac{P(A\cap W=2)}{P(W>0)} &< \frac{P(A\cap W=1)}{P(W=2)} = P(A\mid W=2),\\
  &\qquad\vdots\\[1ex]
 \frac{P(A\cap W=N)}{P(W>0)} &< \frac{P(A\cap W=N)}{P(W=N)} = P(A\mid W=N),
\end{align}

and therefore
$$ P(A\mid W>0) < P(A\mid W=1) + P(A\mid W=2) + \cdots + P(A\mid W=N). $$

In summary, every term in your sum, as you wrote it, is too large by a factor of $P(W>0)/P(W=k).$

We could even say that your mistake is saying that

$$
\frac{a + c + e}{b + d + f} \stackrel?=
\frac ab + \frac cd + \frac ef. 
$$

Comment: thanks for your explanation. Now I see where my logic is flawed. I have one follow up about "In summary, every term in your sum, as you wrote it, is too large by a factor of." Do you arrive at this factor by that I am multiplying each term in my sum by $P(W>0)$ when I should be multiplying it by $P(W=k)$?

Comment: I think of it as effectively dividing by $P(W=k)$ (in order to turn $P(A\cap W=k)$ into $P(A\mid W=k)$) when you should divide by $P(W>0).$ But the effect is the same as your comment.